# magento make last name optional

Tags: customer, magento-1, customer-attribute

i want to make last name optional , can i do it via any setting in admin ?? or what will be best way to do it.. how can i do it via code , i tried setting customer attributes but no sucess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do two things, first, update the attribute last name:

Implement your own setup, depending on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`:

```
$this->updateAttribute('customer', 'last_name', 'is_required', 0);
```

"*Beware of bugs in the above code, I only proved it correct, not tried it*" - Donald Knuth

And second you need to change the registration template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`, and remove the `<em>*</em>` for lastname. Magento will take care of the correct class for JS validation.